# How To Change UIButton Of Same UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a a `UIViewController` that is pushed to by two different views in my app.

One time it is a modal view, so I have the right `navbar` button set to `Done` and it dismisses the view.

At another time in my app, this same view is pushed to, but not modally, thus I don't want this button to show.  I tried adding this when pushing it, but no luck.

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and effective -

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

**Edit:**

How can you add this when you are pushing this ? Add it in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` of the viewController you want to see this is in.

You can check for a certain condition.

1. If it is pushed from view 1, you can make it nil.
2. If it is shown modally from view 2, you can make it appear.

For this, you will have to make the viewControllers communicate with each other. For that, you will need to use `NSUserDefaults` and set an integer for a key.

You can assign two different integers logically and use them as the condition for showing/not showing the `rightBarButtonItem`.

Good Luck.

Comment: I tried adding this when pushing the view from the class that I don't want to show the button, but its still showing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the parent view controller for whether it has the modalViewController property set

```
if (self.parentViewController.modalViewController == self)
{
    // add button
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't show even in the view that is modal.  It is a modal view, buts then 3 views down in hierchy.